# How to install a Canon iP4900 on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, pixma

I have installed printers on many versions of Ubuntu since breezy Badger with no problem. Some weeks ago I installed a new Pixma 4900 in the usual manner, it printed a test file and has not worked since.
     I installed the latest Gutenprint and cups and have been beating my head against the wall trying to get this thing configured.
Can you please provide a sample default file using the latest cupsd,cnf file. I can't even get into local host.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This printer has experimental support in [gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php).

I was able to install it regular way from localhost:631 on Arch linux after installing gutenprint.

But this drivers only have 600*600 DPI resolution for printing which gives really bad results with color prints.

There are also official drivers from Canon for [Linux](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100396702.html) but this drivers have even less features (no color printing at all). I installed them by manually copying files.